# SQLITE : database.locked error - how to wait until one transaction is completed to start the next in a single thread

Tags: database, sqlite, error-handling, locked

We have a thread that receives data continously . this is written to sqldb (method name : dbExecSql) .  Recurringly at every one hour this thread receives a signal from another thread to create a new db  by selecting few rows from the main  and deleting the same in the main db.

this request sometimes occurs inbetween a transaction, the new transaction starts even before the old one is completed and thus database.locked error .

How to resolve this ?

this method writes to db

```
int Database::dbExecSql()
{
.
.
.
 rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertTableSQL.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0);
.
.
 sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);

..
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, j + 1, insertValueInt);
.
.
 rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

 sqlite3_clear_bindings(stmt);
 sqlite3_reset(stmt);

 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);
 rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}
```

this method deletes from db and creates another db. at times while executing detach , we get database.locked error.

```
int Database::dbDelete()
.
.
.
 attachQuery = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + db_log_dir + "/" + system_id + "_" + dbLogName + ".sql'" + " AS '" + system_id + "_" + dbLogName + "';";
 detachQuery = "DETACH DATABASE '" + system_id + "_" + dbLogName + "';";
 copyTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE '" + system_id + "_" + dbLogName + "'.'" + tableName + "_" + dbLogName + "' AS SELECT * FROM main." + tableName;


  deleteQuery = dbDeleteSelected(tableName, timeStart, customLog);

. 
. 
. 
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, attachQuery.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    cout << "ATTACH: " << rc << endl;
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Hour Log Attach: " << err_msg << endl;
        cout << "SQL -> " << attachQuery.c_str() << endl;
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        return rc;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, copyTableQuery.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    cout << "COPY: " << rc << endl;
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Hour Log copyTable: " << err_msg << endl;
        cout << "SQL -> " << copyTableQuery.c_str() << endl;
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        return rc;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, detachQuery.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    cout << "DETACH: " << rc << endl;
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Hour Log Detach: " << err_msg << endl;
        cout << "SQL -> " << detachQuery.c_str() << endl;
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        return rc;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, deleteQuery.c_str(), NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    cout << "DELETE: " << rc << endl;
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Hour Log Deletion: " << err_msg << endl;
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        return rc;
    }
}
```

both the methods are in single thread.

How to ensure the next transaction begin only after the prev is completed .

Comment: You need to synchronize the threads. See locks and semaphores and mutexes.

Comment: @ m0skit0 transactions are in a single thread

Comment: You said: "the new transaction starts even before the old one is completed". How is this supposed to happen if the thread is blocked in the previous transaction?